# nter password: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

nter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is the MySQL daemon running? Can you connect from the command line client?